# NodeJS : wait for a variable to be created before calling a function

Tags: node.js, email, variables, asynchronous

I am kinda new to NodeJS, and working an API for a personnal project. I need to create accounts in a db and then send a confirmation email to the people. So, the route to create an account starts by inserting the data in a database, then getting the insertedId to create a token, and then send a confirmation email with the token inside of it.

I am using db.query() from the mysql package (version 2.18.1) to interact with the database, which is a MySQL database from GCloud:

```js
db.query("INSERT INTO user SET ?", [data], async (iErr, result) => {
    if (iErr) {
        res.status(410).jsonp({msg:iErr});
        next(iErr);
    } else {
        const insertedId = result.insertId;
        let emailToken = await getEmailToken(insertedId);
        // then sending the email using another async method
    }
```

However, the token sent do no have the id inside of it, like if the getEmailToken() used 'undefined' as a parameter.

Does anyone now a solution ?

Thank you.

EDIT : The same issue appears inside of the email, where I put the req.body.name. It is sent as « undefined » in the email, but it is given while calling the route (I store it in the database).

Comment: You'll need to provide some more details. What database are you using? What library are you using to connect to the database from Node.js? Please edit the question and update it with this information.

Comment: why would the email token need the id in it? the function's name suggest it gets you a token, given an id, so it returns a token and then you get to do whatever you need with that, including "sending it, along with the id you already had, to somewhere else"? That said, always look at your console: this code will have printed an error.

Comment: Hey, sorry I am new to StackOverflow, I edited my post adding the information.

Comment: The email token is a confirmation token. I need to send it by email, so the users can verify their accounts. That’s the reason why I need to generate a unique token to send it by email to the user, with their id inside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mysql` package README documents the way to obtain the newly-inserted ID: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#getting-the-id-of-an-inserted-row

There are several problems with the callback in your code:

- It looks like the order of the arguments may be wrong - the documentation has it like this - notice how the results object is the second argument, not third. So, you may be getting "result" under "rows".

> connection.query('INSERT INTO posts SET ?', {title: 'test'}, function (error, results, fields)

- The `mysql` library uses `insertId`. This is easy to mistake for `insertedId`, which is used in MongoDB, but they are not the same word.

Comment: As I said above, I made a mistake. I am using the good arguments. However, at the end of the function, i send a response 200 to the user with the insertedId inside of it, and it works, it just doesn’t work inside of the token generation function.

Comment: Are you sure it works with "insertedId", not insertId? mysql driver source uses insertId: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/blob/3430c513d6b0ca279fb7c79b210c9301e9315658/lib/protocol/packets/OkPacket.js#L21

Comment: Yes it works. I use the same variable in the response and in the token generation function.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) package, according to doc, db.query's callback get 3 parameters first error second result third fields.Like so:

```
db.query("INSERT INTO user SET ?", [data], async (err, result, fields) => {}
```

Comment: I made a mistake while doing the post, « result » was used in the code. Just changed it in the post.

Comment: ok, sorry. i added new solve:)

Comment: You are right. However, the issues stays the same (I have edited my post)